# Retornar valor correspondente a data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela com valores e com datas referente ao custo de um veículo. Porém a tabela é preenchida da seguinte forma:

```
data_saida | custo_saida
-------------------------
2019-11-17 | 25
2019-11-18 | 20
null       | 10
```

O preenchimento é feito dessa forma pois os dias específicos são menos comuns, e agiliza no input de informação do usuário.

Eu preciso que quando a data_saida for 17/11 retorne o custo_saida 25, quando for 18/11 retorne 20, e quaisquer outros dias retorne 10 (exemplo: 19, 20 e 21/11).

Já tentei diversas querys e nenhuma obtive sucesso:

```
SELECT custo_saida 
FROM tabela WHERE data_saida = COALESCE('2019-11-19', null::date)
```

A query acima retorna o custo_saida correto quando a data procurada corresponde com as datas na tabela, porém não retorna nenhum valor quando a data_saida é outra data qualquer, como no exemplo 19/11.

```
SELECT custo_saida 
FROM tabela WHERE (data_saida = '2019-11-19' OR data_saida is null)
```

Já a query anterior retorna correto quando a data procurada não foi definida no campo data_saida da tabela, porém quando procuro por uma data que esteja definida, por exemplo 18/11, ele me retorna os valores 20 e 10.

E eu preciso dessa query para ser subquery de uma principal, sendo assim, ela precisa retornar apenas um valor.

Há alguma forma para fazer isso?

Comment: Pela sua explicação podemos concluir que podem existir data_saida em sua tabela que não estejam associadas a um custo_saida?

Comment: @anonimo Na verdade é o contrário, há custo_saida sem data_saida associada. Se for informada uma data que não conter na planilha, essa data_saida receberá o custo_saida onde a data_saida é null. E quando for informada uma data_saida que conter na planilha, retornará o valor do custo_saida correspondente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isto:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tabela aux1 WHERE aux1.data_saida = data_desejada::date) 
                        THEN (SELECT custo_saida FROM tabela WHERE data_saida = data_desejada::date) 
                        ELSE (SELECT custo_saida FROM tabela WHERE data_saida IS NULL) 
          END) AS custo_saida;
```

Comment: Funciona para o que eu perguntei porém preciso retornar também a data_saida (eu esqueci de editar a pergunta).

Comment: Você precisa retornar a data_saida ou a data_desejada? Note que a data_saida será NULL se ela não existir em sua tabela.

Comment: Isso, preciso da data_desejada, consegui fazer inserindo a data_desejada após o custo_saida. Vou avaliar qual  é a melhor opção.

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN data_saida is null THEN 10 ELSE custo_saida END AS custo_saida
FROM tabela
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma. Basta substituir a data `2019-11-19` pela data que deseja procurar.

```sql
SELECT custo_saida
FROM tabela
WHERE (data_saida = '2019-11-19' OR data_saida IS NULL)
ORDER BY data_saida DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @thiagofred, este comando resolveu a sua necessidade? Na outra resposta você disse que tinha que retornar o campo *data_desejada*. Basta adicionar no SELECT após o campo *custo_saida*

Comment: Sim, este comando também é uma forma de resolver a minha necessidade.